# SwiftUI - Getting the first index of a JSON request, Fatal error: Index out of range

Tags: swiftui, sdwebimage

Im attempting to get the property of the first object in an array from a JSON request using WebImage. How can I receive the first value of the JSON when loaded and then replace it with a placeholder image when the data is loaded?

I set the index of the first image of the data like this.

> searchObjectController.results[0].urls.small

But I recieve the error

> Thread 1: Fatal error: Index out of range

Here is the Struct for the JSON

```
struct Results : Codable {
    var total : Int
    var results : [Result]
}

struct Result : Codable {
    var id : String
    var description : String?
    var urls : URLs
}

struct URLs : Codable {
    var small : String
}
```

this is the view where the image is presented.

```
struct HomeView: View {
    
    @EnvironmentObject var searchObjectController: SearchObjectController

    
    var body: some View {
                    
        NavigationView {
            
                
                VStack {
                    HStack {
                        
                    }
                    NavigationLink(destination: CameraView()
                    ) {
                        
                        Label("Snap", systemImage: "camera")
                            .foregroundColor(Color.purple)
                            .padding(20)
                            .border(Color.purple, width: 2)
                    }
                    
                    
                    Text("topic for today: \(searchObjectController.searchText)")
                        .fontWeight(.bold)
                        .padding(6)
                    
                    NavigationLink(destination: GenerateView()) {
                        WebImage(url: URL(string: searchObjectController.results[0].urls.small))
                            .resizable()
                            .scaledToFill()
                                .frame(height: 100, alignment: .center)
                                .clipped()
                            .cornerRadius(10)
                            .overlay(ImageOverlay(), alignment: .topLeading)
                    }
                        
                    
                    Spacer()
                }.navigationBarTitle("DrawDaily")
        }
    }
}
```

the JSON request class where the JSON is loaded. I am using Unsplash API for context

```
class SearchObjectController : ObservableObject {
    
    var token = "gQR-YsX0OpwkYpbjhPVi3b4kSR-DtWrR5phwDm2kPMM"
    @Published var results = [Result]()
    @Published var searchText : String = "whales"
    
    func search () {
        let url = URL(string: "https://api.unsplash.com/search/photos?query=\(searchText)")
        var request = URLRequest(url: url!)
        request.httpMethod = "GET"
        request.setValue("Client-ID \(token)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
        print("request: \(request)")
        
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
            guard let data = data else {return}
            print(String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)!)

            do {
                let res = try JSONDecoder().decode(Results.self, from: data)
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.results.append(contentsOf: res.results)
                }
                //print(self.results)
            } catch {
                print("catch: \(error)")
            }
        }
        task.resume()
    } }
```

Comment: The crash occurs if the array is empty. Get the first item safely by optional binding `first`. And as you deliberately declare `small` as optional why do you force unwrap it?

Comment: Hi vadian. I was just trying out diffferent ways. Will change that optional back and remove the force unwrap. Do you mind showing me in a code example what you mean by "Get the first item safely by optional binding first." Sorry I am new to swift.

Comment: Try to change with `var results: [Result]?` and add the optional `?? "something"` where it is needed

Comment: Thanks! that seemed to work.